# python nested dict reorganization to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, transformation

Do you know if there is a quick method to do the following dictionary transformation? (without looping through dict's keys and construct it from scratch)

From this nested python dictionary:

```
{
    "demographicAll": {
        "allAges": {
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "2327099"
        },
        "agesUnder18": {
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "1050"
        },
        "ages18To29": {
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "363089"
        },
        "ages30To44": {
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "914737"
        },
        "agesOver45": {
            "rating": "8.2",
            "votes": "182612"
        }
    }
}
```

to this one:

```
{

    "demographicAll": [
        {
            "ageRange": "allAges",
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "2327099"
        },{
            "ageRange": "agesUnder18",
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "1050"
        },{
            "ageRange": "ages18To29",
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "363089"
        },{
            "ageRange": "ages30To44",
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "914737"
        },{
            "ageRange": "agesOver45",
            "rating": "8.2",
            "votes": "182612"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `[{'newkey': k, **v} for k, v in d.items()]`.

Comment: I obviously still have my tendency to overcomplicate things :)

Comment: Very elegant way to solve this thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I was able to do (it still loops through the dictionary inside the list comprehension) is:

```
mydict =    {
    "demographicAll": {
        "allAges": {
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "2327099"
        },
        "agesUnder18": {
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "1050"
        },
        "ages18To29": {
            "rating": "9.0",
            "votes": "363089"
        },
        "ages30To44": {
            "rating": "8.8",
            "votes": "914737"
        },
        "agesOver45": {
            "rating": "8.2",
            "votes": "182612"
        }
    }
}

d = mydict["demographicAll"]
mydict["demographicAll"] = [d[key] for key in d if not d[key].update({'ageRange':key})]
```

Comment: You're welcome; of course you can replace the 2nd part of the 2nd line with @ekhumoro's solution.